# Can I give a Stored Procedure permission to SET IDENTITY_INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I would like to give permission to insert identities while not giving the restricted user calling it ALTER TABLE privileges. Is that possible?

Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddInternalQu] 
(
    @id [int],
    @qu [nvarchar](500),
    @pg [nvarchar](50),
    @isactive [bit],
    @isdoc [bit],
    @allowNA [bit],
    @textBox [bit],
    @redf [bit],
    @qord [int],
    @shqu [nvarchar](50),
    @restrict [bit],
    @scanwizard [bit]
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [questions] ON;

    INSERT INTO [questions] (qu_id, question, shortqu, redflag, page, active, is_doc_qu, 
                             allowNA, textBox, qu_order, scanwizard, restricted) 
    VALUES(@id, @qu, @shqu, @redf, @pg, @isactive, @isdoc, 
           @allowNA, @textBox, @qord, @scanwizard, @restrict);

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [questions] OFF;
END

GRANT EXEC ON AddInternalQu TO MyStandardRole;
```

As it stands a user I add to the `MyStandardRole` role has the rights to execute the stored procedure but then it fails trying to set the identity insert with insufficient privileges.

Comment: This is a bad idea no matter what. Identity_insert should not be called from a stored proc because you should not routinely be going around the identity setting. If you want to get around the identiy, then you should not have an identity column. This setting is meant only to be used for very occasional transfer of data from other systems and the like but never for daily use in a stored proc a user can access. Why on earth do you want to do such thing?

Comment: Some of the questions are hard coded system questions and I want them to have fixed ids. I still want auto id for all other questions. I can see that changing the design would be better, but is a big change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER" should do the trick.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddInternalQu] 
(
    @id [int],
    @qu [nvarchar](500),
    @pg [nvarchar](50),
    @isactive [bit],
    @isdoc [bit],
    @allowNA [bit],
    @textBox [bit],
    @redf [bit],
    @qord [int],
    @shqu [nvarchar](50),
    @restrict [bit],
    @scanwizard [bit]
)
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [questions] ON;

    INSERT INTO [questions] (qu_id, question, shortqu, redflag, page, active, is_doc_qu, 
                             allowNA, textBox, qu_order, scanwizard, restricted) 
    VALUES(@id, @qu, @shqu, @redf, @pg, @isactive, @isdoc, 
           @allowNA, @textBox, @qord, @scanwizard, @restrict);

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [questions] OFF;
END

GRANT EXEC ON AddInternalQu TO MyStandardRole;
```